# Move table view down programatically? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way that I can move down the top of my table view proramatically? (So that there is a gap between the navigation bar and the start of the table view)

Comment: Do you want something to go in that space, or do you just want there to be space? [tableHeaderView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) can be good for putting something in that space.

Comment: @Deyton I already have a table header view, but I need to show a search bar in it and thus make the height larger and shift everything down (when the search button is clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the [`contentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset) property on the `UITableView`.  Set the top edge to be the gap you desire.

Alternatively, set the `frame.origin` property, or add a value to the constraint you used to set the top of the frame, if you're using constraint-based layout.